# Package: pifont

Tags: packages

What does the following message mean? The line indicated has a command which relates to how I call the theorems, lemmas and so on.

```
Package: pifont 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Pi font support (SPQR) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+pzd on input line 63.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\upzd.fd"
File: upzd.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/pzd.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+psy on input line 64.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\psnfss\upsy.fd"
File: upsy.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for U/psy.
)
! Font U/psy/m/n/10.95=psyr at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.64 {\Pifont{psy}
                  }
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You probably have a corrupt installation, because the metric files for Symbol should be available. Try reinstalling the MiKTeX package `psnfss` with MiKTeX's package manager.